# Data between selected row to Uiviewcontroller containing a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried to pass data between the selected row to UITableview inside of UIView .
i have a void prepare segue in in the selected row, where i query the images then call a PFFile then save the NSData inside of image. But i am stucked in the ViewController that contains the UITableview, because the image its not save in array i am having great difficulty to show the data in the ViewController any help.
This code is prepare segue to pass the data.

```
    NSIndexPath*indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NewViewController *destination=(NewViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    PFObject *object=[self.arrayusers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"image"];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if(object)
        {
            PFFile *file=[object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
            [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if(data)
                {
                    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

                }
                    }];
        }
            }];
```

Comment: your array is empty?

Comment: before i was using an array but it wasnt working ,the UIImage has the image i am just having problem to get those image in the other tableview, so i try to save the image to an array but it keep saying null

Comment: are you sure that you have images in your data? and block is called late

Comment: yes i have them because i NSLOG  then i saw all the image id so i went to parse it was the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024812/parse-ios-sdk-not-able-to-fetch-objects-from-array  is this helpful?

Comment: not really , but what i am trying to is that is newspaper app when you tap row inside tableview that contains the author of the newspaper you will see the a newviewcontrller that has the authors name and the article they wrote .So once you tap on the row u will see all articles this user wrote .

Comment: your next view dosn t show anything?

Comment: only the author name , so i was thinking to save That UIImage inside of array that was declare in the second view but i wasnt working